# No views in hierarchy found matching: Child at position 0 in parent Child at position 0 in parent view.getId

Tags: java, android, testing, expresso

I created an instrumental test with android studio, using Express Record Test. 
 
Flow: 
-> Starts in the Activity_splash_screen class. 
-> Then the LoginActivity.java screen goes to the screen. 
-> After the login screen goes to another actitivity (ValuesPeternActivity.java) that asks for the DDI, the phone and a user ID. 
Ending the flow in HomeActivity.java

1 ° The test fills in the login and password fields; (success) 
2 ° Click on the next heading to a new screen; (success) 
3 ° An error occurs because it stops in the txtDDI field, which is the first field on the second screen. (error)

If I insist on executing repeatedly, sometimes the test passes, sometimes not even the first screen test passes. I believe it characterizes a lack of synchrony between the express and the thread.

How to sync? 
I found out about it but I was unable to implement it. see link -> [IdlingRegistry and Espresso will wait for the resource](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/espresso/IdlingResource)

I saw a video in which the guy was doing this test and didn't need any of that. It must be because of androidx, it can only!

Mistake of error:

```
Started running tests


        androidx.test.espresso.NoMatchingViewException: No views in hierarchy found matching: Child at position 0 in parent Child at position 0 in parent view.getId() is <2131296889/br.com.cellsgroupleader:id/txtDDI>

        View Hierarchy:
        +>DecorView{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1366, height=406, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, layout-params={(0,0)(wrapxwrap) gr=CENTER sim={adjust=pan} ty=APPLICATION fmt=TRANSLUCENT wanim=0x10302f9
          fl=DIM_BEHIND FULLSCREEN ALT_FOCUSABLE_IM SPLIT_TOUCH HARDWARE_ACCELERATED}, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=1} |
        +----->Space{id=16909413, res-name=titleDividerNoCustom, visibility=GONE, width=0, height=0, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=true, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams@d7e62e0, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0} 
        |
        +---->FrameLayout{id=16908813, res-name=contentPanel, visibility=GONE, width=0, height=0, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=true, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams@5ed645e, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=1} 
        +------->Space{id=16909395, res-name=textSpacerNoTitle, visibility=VISIBLE, width=0, height=0, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=true, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams@550d2d1, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0} 
        |
        +------->AppCompatTextView{id=16908299, res-name=message, visibility=GONE, width=0, height=0, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=true, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams@24ba136, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, text=, input-type=0, ime-target=false, has-links=false} 
        |
        +------->Space{id=16909394, res-name=textSpacerNoButtons, visibility=VISIBLE, width=0, height=0, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=true, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams@b164837, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0} 
        |
        +---->FrameLayout{id=16908820, res-name=customPanel, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1254, height=294, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams@83ecb0d, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=1} 
        |
        +----->FrameLayout{id=16908331, res-name=custom, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1254, height=294, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams@3fd30d3, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=1}
        |
        +---->ScrollView{id=16908766, res-name=buttonPanel, visibility=GONE, width=0, height=0, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=true, is-layout-requested=true, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams@16fe74b, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=1} 
        |
        +----->ButtonBarLayout{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=0, height=0, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=true, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams@d8ccbd4, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=4} 
        |
        +------>AppCompatButton{id=16908315, res-name=button3, visibility=GONE, width=0, height=0, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=true, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=true, is-layout-requested=true, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams@505917d, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, text=, input-type=0, ime-target=false, has-links=false} 
        |
        +------>Space{id=16909328, res-name=spacer, visibility=INVISIBLE, width=0, height=0, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=true, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams@9613872, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0} 
        |
        +------>AppCompatButton{id=16908314, res-name=button2, visibility=GONE, width=0, height=0, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=true, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=true, is-layout-requested=true, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams@7c3f4c3, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, text=, input-type=0, ime-target=false, has-links=false} 
        |
        +------>AppCompatButton{id=16908313, res-name=button1, visibility=GONE, width=0, height=0, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=true, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=true, is-layout-requested=true, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams@4d4d140, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, text=, input-type=0, ime-target=false, has-links=false} 
        |
        +-->ViewStub{id=16908682, res-name=action_mode_bar_stub, visibility=GONE, width=0, height=0, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=true, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams@ddec879, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0} 
        |
            at dalvik.system.VMStack.getThreadStackTrace(Native Method)
            at java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace(Thread.java:1538)
            at androidx.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler.getUserFriendlyError(DefaultFailureHandler.java:12)
            at androidx.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler.handle(DefaultFailureHandler.java:7)
            at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.waitForAndHandleInteractionResults(ViewInteraction.java:8)
            at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.desugaredPerform(ViewInteraction.java:11)
            at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.perform(ViewInteraction.java:4)
            at br.com.cellsgroupleader.Activity_splash_screenTest.activity_splash_screenTest(Activity_splash_screenTest.java:111)

        Tests ran to completion.
```

Activity_splash_screen_Test generated by the Express Record Test 
Here I had to put editText.check (matches (withText (endsWith ("joseb@gmail.com")))). 
The endWidth help to take only what is necessary, because I was making a mistake here.

```
package br.com.cellsgroupleader;

        import android.content.*;
        import android.view.*;

        import androidx.test.espresso.*;
        import androidx.test.filters.*;
        import androidx.test.platform.app.*;
        import androidx.test.rule.*;
        import androidx.test.runner.*;

        import org.hamcrest.Description;
        import org.hamcrest.*;
        import org.junit.*;
        import org.junit.runner.*;

        import static androidx.test.espresso.Espresso.*;
        import static androidx.test.espresso.action.ViewActions.closeSoftKeyboard;
        import static androidx.test.espresso.action.ViewActions.*;
        import static androidx.test.espresso.assertion.ViewAssertions.*;
        import static androidx.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.*;
        import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.*;
        import static org.junit.Assert.*;

        @LargeTest
        @RunWith( AndroidJUnit4.class )
        public class Activity_splash_screenTest{
           
           @Rule
           public ActivityTestRule < Activity_splash_screen > mActivityTestRule = new ActivityTestRule <>( Activity_splash_screen.class );
          
           @Test
           public void useAppContext( ){
              // Context of the app under test.
              Context appContext = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation( ).getTargetContext( );
              assertEquals( "br.com.cellsgroupleader" , appContext.getPackageName( ) );
           }
           
           @Test
           public void activity_splash_screenTest( ){
              ViewInteraction textInputEditText = onView(
                 childAtPosition(
                    childAtPosition(
                       withId(R.id.email) ,
                       0 ) ,
                    0 ) );
                    textInputEditText.perform( scrollTo( ) , click( ) );
              
              ViewInteraction textInputEditText2 = onView(
                 childAtPosition(
                    childAtPosition(
                       withId( R.id.email ) ,
                       0 ) ,
                    0 ) );
              textInputEditText2.perform( scrollTo( ) , replaceText( "joseb@gmail.com" ) , closeSoftKeyboard( ) );
              
              ViewInteraction textInputEditText3 = onView(
                 allOf( withText( "joseb@gmail.com" ) ,
                    childAtPosition(
                       childAtPosition(
                          withId( R.id.email ) ,
                          0 ) ,
                       0 ) ) );
              textInputEditText3.perform( pressImeActionButton( ) );
              
              ViewInteraction textInputEditText4 = onView(
                 childAtPosition(
                    childAtPosition(
                       withId( R.id.password ) ,
                       0 ) ,
                    0 ) );
              textInputEditText4.perform( scrollTo( ) , replaceText( "123456" ) , closeSoftKeyboard( ) );
              
              ViewInteraction textInputEditText5 = onView(
                 allOf( withText( "123456" ) ,
                    childAtPosition(
                       childAtPosition(
                          withId( R.id.password ) ,
                          0 ) ,
                       0 ) ) );
              textInputEditText5.perform( pressImeActionButton( ) );
              
              ViewInteraction editText = onView(
                 allOf( withText( "joseb@gmail.com" ) ,
                    withParent( withParent( withId( R.id.email ) ) ) ,
                    isDisplayed( ) ) );
              editText.check( matches( withText(endsWith("joseb@gmail.com")) ) );
              
              ViewInteraction editText2 = onView(
                 allOf( withText( "123456" ) ,
                    withParent( withParent( withId( R.id.password ) ) ) ,
                    isDisplayed( ) ) );
              editText2.check( matches( withText(endsWith("123456")) ) );
              
              ViewInteraction appCompatButton = onView(
                 allOf( withId( R.id.btnEnviarLogin ) , withText( "Entrar" ) ,
                    childAtPosition(
                       childAtPosition(
                          withClassName( is( "android.widget.LinearLayout" ) ) ,
                          4 ) ,
                       1 ) ) );
              appCompatButton.perform( scrollTo( ) , click( ) );
           
              ViewInteraction textInputEditText6 = onView(
                 childAtPosition(
                    childAtPosition(
                       withId( R.id.txtDDI ) ,
                       0 ) ,
                    0 ) );
              textInputEditText6.perform( scrollTo( ) , replaceText( "+55" ) , closeSoftKeyboard( ) );
           
              ViewInteraction textInputEditText7 = onView(
                 allOf( withText( "+55" ) ,
                    childAtPosition(
                       childAtPosition(
                          withId( R.id.txtDDI ) ,
                          0 ) ,
                       0 ) ) );
              textInputEditText7.perform( pressImeActionButton( ) );
           
              ViewInteraction textInputEditText14 = onView(
                 allOf( withText( "(48)96456-5896" ) ,
                    childAtPosition(
                       childAtPosition(
                          withId( R.id.txtfone ) ,
                          0 ) ,
                       0 ) ,
                    isDisplayed( ) ) );
              textInputEditText14.perform( closeSoftKeyboard( ) );
           
              ViewInteraction textInputEditText15 = onView(
                 allOf( withText( "(48)96456-5896" ) ,
                    childAtPosition(
                       childAtPosition(
                          withId( R.id.txtfone ) ,
                          0 ) ,
                       0 ) ) );
              textInputEditText15.perform( pressImeActionButton( ) );
           
              ViewInteraction textInputEditText16 = onView(
                 childAtPosition(
                    childAtPosition(
                       withId( R.id.txtcodigoID ) ,
                       0 ) ,
                    0 ) );
              textInputEditText16.perform( scrollTo( ) , longClick( ) );
           
              ViewInteraction linearLayout = onView(
                 allOf( withContentDescription( "Colar" ) ,
                    childAtPosition(
                       childAtPosition(
                          withClassName( is( "android.widget.RelativeLayout" ) ) ,
                          1 ) ,
                       0 ) ,
                    isDisplayed( ) ) );
              linearLayout.perform( click( ) );
           
              ViewInteraction textInputEditText17 = onView(
                 childAtPosition(
                    childAtPosition(
                       withId( R.id.txtcodigoID ) ,
                       0 ) ,
                    0 ) );
              textInputEditText17.perform( scrollTo( ) , replaceText( "-MU7CLJOxn3s8iG7l9MS" ) , closeSoftKeyboard( ) );
           
              ViewInteraction textInputEditText18 = onView(
                 allOf( withText( "-MU7CLJOxn3s8iG7l9MS" ) ,
                    childAtPosition(
                       childAtPosition(
                          withId( R.id.txtcodigoID ) ,
                          0 ) ,
                       0 ) ) );
              textInputEditText18.perform( pressImeActionButton( ) );
           
              ViewInteraction editText3 = onView(
                 allOf( withText( "+55" ) ,
                    withParent( withParent( withId( R.id.txtDDI ) ) ) ,
                    isDisplayed( ) ) );
              editText3.check( matches( withText( "+55" ) ) );
           
              ViewInteraction editText4 = onView(
                 allOf( withText( "(48)96456-5896" ) ,
                    withParent( withParent( withId( R.id.txtfone ) ) ) ,
                    isDisplayed( ) ) );
              editText4.check( matches( withText( "(48)96456-5896" ) ) );
           
              ViewInteraction editText5 = onView(
                 allOf( withText( "-MU7CLJOxn3s8iG7l9MS" ) ,
                    withParent( withParent( withId( R.id.txtcodigoID ) ) ) ,
                    isDisplayed( ) ) );
              editText5.check( matches( withText( "-MU7CLJOxn3s8iG7l9MS" ) ) );
           
              ViewInteraction appCompatButton2 = onView(
                 allOf( withId( R.id.txtAvancar ) , withText( "Avançar" ) ,
                    childAtPosition(
                       childAtPosition(
                          withClassName( is( "android.widget.ScrollView" ) ) ,
                          0 ) ,
                       6 ) ) );
              appCompatButton2.perform( scrollTo( ) , click( ) );
           }
           
           
           
           private static Matcher < View > childAtPosition(
              final Matcher < View > parentMatcher , final int position ){
              
              return new TypeSafeMatcher < View >( ){
                 @Override
                 public void describeTo( Description description ){
                    description.appendText( "Child at position " + position + " in parent " );
                    parentMatcher.describeTo( description );
                 }
                 
                 @Override
                 public boolean matchesSafely( View view ){
                    ViewParent parent = view.getParent( );
                    return parent instanceof ViewGroup && parentMatcher.matches( parent )
                       && view.equals( ( ( ViewGroup ) parent ).getChildAt( position ) );
                 }
              };
           }
        }
```

./gradle

```
plugins {
            id 'com.android.application'
            id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
        }

        android {
            signingConfigs {
                release {
                    storeFile file('/home/fsp/Área de Trabalho/PRIVATE KEYS ANDROID/KEYS_ANDROID')
                    storePassword ''
                    keyAlias ''
                    keyPassword ''
                }
                debug {
                    storeFile file('/home/fsp/Área de Trabalho/PRIVATE KEYS ANDROID/KEYS_ANDROID')
                    storePassword ''
                    keyAlias ''
                    keyPassword ''
                }
            }
            compileSdkVersion 30
            buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

            defaultConfig {
                applicationId "br.com.cellsgroupleader"
                minSdkVersion 23
                targetSdkVersion 30
                versionCode 1
                versionName "1.0.1"
                testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
                signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            }
            testOptions {
                unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
            }
            useLibrary 'android.test.runner'
            useLibrary 'android.test.base'
            useLibrary 'android.test.mock'

            compileOptions {
                sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
                targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
            }
            ndkVersion '21.3.6528147'
            buildTypes {
                release {
                    signingConfig signingConfigs.release
                }
                debug {
                    signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
                }
            }
        }

        dependencies {
            implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
            implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
            implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
            implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
            implementation 'androidx.preference:preference:1.1.1'

            //noinspection GradleDependency
            implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.3.2'

            //noinspection GradleDependency
            implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.3.2'
            implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
            implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
            implementation 'androidx.drawerlayout:drawerlayout:1.1.1'
            implementation 'androidx.coordinatorlayout:coordinatorlayout:1.1.0'

            //noinspection GradleDependency
            implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha02'
            implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:20.0.2'
            implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:19.0.0'
            implementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-intents:3.4.0-alpha04'
            androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:rules:1.3.0'

            //noinspection GradleDependency
            implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'

            // Required -- JUnit 4 framework
            testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
            // Optional -- Robolectric environment
            testImplementation 'androidx.test:core:1.3.0'
            // Optional -- Mockito framework
            testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'

            // Core library
            androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:core:1.3.0'

            // AndroidJUnitRunner and JUnit Rules
            androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.3.0'
            androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:rules:1.3.0'

            // Assertions
            androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
            androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:truth:1.3.0'
            androidTestImplementation 'com.google.truth:truth:1.0'

            // Espresso dependencies
            androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
            androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:3.3.0'
            androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-intents:3.3.0'
            androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-accessibility:3.3.0'
            androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-web:3.3.0'
            androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso.idling:idling-concurrent:3.3.0'

            //firebase
            implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-functions:19.2.0'
            implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:19.2.1'
            implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.3.0')
            implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
            implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.6.0'
            implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:20.0.2'
            implementation 'com.github.prolificinteractive:material-calendarview:1.4.3'

            //glide
            implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'
            implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
            //noinspection GradleDependency
            implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-dynamic-features-fragment:2.3.2'
            annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.8.0'
        }
```

Comment: Hey, Did you get any solution?